# Correct gear cable for vintage Shimano 600 derailleur?

Tags: shimano, gears, derailleur, vintage

I'm restoring an old bicycle and need gear cables for this derailleur (see photo). I found some specs here https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=9422ABE1-A7B3-4622-9DAB-EF4DEC646ED5 but it doesn't tell me which gear cable I need. It's either 1.1mm or 1.2mm I think?

Thanks!

[image: Shimano 600]

Answer (score 6):

It really makes no difference - the rear derailleur has a pinch bolt that will hold either.

You might choose an outer that looks matt black, rather than the modern glossy outers if you want a period-correct look.   Personally I'd go for a lubed stainless steel cable, rather than the dull grey galvinised cable it would have had originally.

Also, you need the right head end inside the shifter, whatever that is on yours.

Good luck !